# whats wrong in this simple encrypt and decrypt program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

```
def enc(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if (i%2==0):
            a[i]=chr(ord(a[i])+3)
        else:
            a[i]=chr(ord(a[i])+5)
    r1 = ''.join(a)
    return r1

def dec(m):
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if (i%2==0):
            m[i]=chr(ord(m[i])-3)
        else:
            m[i]=chr(ord(m[i]+5)
    r2 = ''.join(m)
    return r2
h=input()
print(enc(h))
print(dec(h))
```

please help me solve this probably stupid bug,i just want an input and encrpyt and decrypt it

Comment: the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Hi there, what's the bug? If I run the code, I could say that it "works" fine and is "bug"-free whatever the output/error. Please describe why your code doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Works on my machine.  Or doesn't work on my machine.  I can't tell.  What are the expected (correct) results, versus what are the actual (wrong) results?

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of fun reading your code, because some time ago I attempted to write encryption and decryption myself. So I think I know what you want to achive.

So first of all, Python strings don't like assignements.

**So we convert the string to a list**

```
def enc(a):
   a = list(a)
```

**After that we look at your calls**

```
h=input()
print(enc(h))
print(dec(h))
```

**These calls will just produce some "random" strings, so I propose:**

```
h=input()
h= enc(h)
print(h)
print(dec(h))
```

This will encrypt the string, than it will print the string. Pass it to the dec method and print the string you've entered after rollingback on the changes in enc.

**At last but not least, we have to look at your dec method:**

```
else:
      m[i]=chr(ord(m[i]+5)
```

If you use +5 like in enc, you will never be able to get the original string back, which should be the most important thing in encryption and decryption.

**So you would have to change it to**

```
else:
      m[i]=chr(ord(m[i])-5)
```

**So if you change that all, the final code should look like that:**

```
def enc(a):
   a = list(a)
   for i in range(len(a)):
      if (i%2==0):
           a[i]=str(chr(ord(a[i])+3))
       else:
           a[i]=str(chr(ord(a[i])+5))
   r1 = ''.join(a)
   return r1

def dec(m):
    m = list(m)
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if (i%2==0):
            m[i]=str(chr(ord(m[i])-3))
        else:
            m[i]=str(chr(ord(m[i])-5))
    string2 = "".join(m)
    return string2


h = "Hallo"
h = enc(h)
print(h)
print(dec(h))
```

So for the string "Welcome to StackOverflow" the output will be:

```
after enc: Zjohrrh%wt#XwffpR{hwiqr|
after dec: Welcome to StackOverflow
```